Understanding proportionality
I’ve recently come across the concept of proportionality during my time in university and it’s been presented differently compared to when I first learn it.
Initially, I was taught that 2 variables are either directly or inversely proportional. If they are directly proportional, then as x increases then y increases and if x decreases then y decreases. Additionally, I was taught that inversely proportional meant that if x decreases y increases and if x increases y decreases.
In university, I have now been taught the concept of proportionality without direct or indirect proportionality. I have been told that y is proportional to x if y = kx.
Now, joining the 2 concepts with some further readings, I understood that y is directly proportional to x if y=kx, but my question is, what happens if k is negative? From my observation on a graph, I see that as x increases, y decreases.
The only justification I can think of is that when we look at the increase or the rate of change in x and y, technically they both change by a positive rate due to the negative values cancelling one another out.
Is this justification correct? Can anyone provide further clarity regarding this concept.

"Inversely proportional" means $y=\frac kx$, not what you say.

I always thought that proportionality statements were generally only made for varying positive quantities. As for In university, I have now been taught, I think you'll find throughout your life that few words and conventions are "absolutes". For example, where I live, people drive on the right side of the road, and in other places people drive on the left side of the road. So instead of "I have now been taught", probably a more correct view of the situation is "I am now learning of the convention".

@DaveL.Renfro that’s what I thought until I started mathematical modelling and I was given an example with a negative proportionality constant

negative proportionality constant -- Humm... To be honest, I don't know whether this is someone who doesn't know better or a reflection of my "school math" limitations of using proportionality notions.

@DaveL.Renfro what is the issue with the term “negative proportionality constant”?

I don't think I've encountered anything more than school math stuff such as "$x:y = 2:3$" (as meaning "$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{2}{3}$" or "$x=2k$ and $y=3k$ for some $k>0$") and "$V$ is proportional to the cube of $r$" (as meaning "$V = kr^3$ for some $k>0$"). Outside of school math, I think these notions and terminology show up in various natural and social science areas much more than in mathematics, where one more often will encounter terms like dilation, Lipschitz transformation, contraction mapping, order of growth, etc.

If you want clarity, then be aware of this: The way you have been understanding proportionality is wrong, and you should forget it. For one thing, you already found one issue yourself. For another, "y increases if x increases" is very imprecise and
a) doesn't cover all cases of proportionality (the one you take issue with, for instance), and
b) covers cases which are no proportionality at all, like exponential growth.
Both a) and b) apply to your understanding of inverse proportionality as well. For instance, in exponential decay of a radioactive substance, the number of particles decreases with time, but the number of particles is not inversely proportional to time.
Here is how you should understand it:
A variable $y$ is proportional to a variable $y$ if doubling, tripling, halving, etc., $x$ leads to doubling, tripling, halving, etc., of $y$. To make it more precise: $y$ is proportional to $x$ if multiplying $x$ by any number $c$ leads to $y$ being multiplied by that same number. This is equivalent to $y=kx$ for some number $k$. As an example, if I start with 0 \$ in my bank account and spend 5 \$ every day, then my account balance is proportional to the number of days past, since doubling the days doubles my balance (same with tripling, halving, etc.): The double of -5 \$ is -10 \$, and thats what I have in my account after two days.
This is also known as direct proportionality, which is just a longer way of saying proportionality. Inverse proportionality means something different: $y$ is inversely proportional to $x$ if it is proportional to the inverse of $x$, that is, $y$ is proportional to $\frac 1x$. Important: If $y$ is inversely proportional to $x$, then it is not proportional to $x$ (unless $y=0$ independently of $x$). Proportionality is not an umbrella term for both direct and inverse proportionality.

Thank you for your response. So if y is proportional to $\frac{1}{x}$ then does that mean it is directly proportional to $\frac{1}{x}$ ?

@Oofy2000 Directly proportional and proportional mean the same thing. The point of qualifying proportionality as "directly" or "inversely" is just that in both cases $y$ is proportional to something. But in the inverse case it's proportional to a derived quantity $\frac 1x$, while in the inverse case there is no intermediate step: $y$ is "directly" proportional to $x$, not to something derived from $x$.
